# Possible to create a pip freeze requirements file off the libraries used in a single directory or file?

Tags: python, pip

I use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in my directory and it stores all the installed libraries on my machine. Is it possible to reduce this down to the libraries used in this directory or maybe just a single python file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a few options. One is brute force use grep to find all the import statements in your files.

Another option, check out Snakefood:
http://furius.ca/snakefood/doc/snakefood-doc.html

Simple tool you can use to print out python dependencies. Can be as simple as

```
sfood-imports yourfile.py
```

And you can extend it using the --unified flag to print out the set of unique libraries you need for the files in a directory.